# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Using Intellij IDEA 13 in a Desktop application

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, runtime-error, openjpa

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 13, and I'm creating a desktop application using Maven and OpenJPA, but do not know why I get a error message, this error occurs when running the Main file, I start the application, but pressing search button for searching a "Cliente" in the database, this error occurs:

```
1006  sacPU  WARN   [AWT-EventQueue-0] openjpa.Enhance - An exception was thrown while attempting to perform class file transformation on "cl/im/sac/Model/Cliente":
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cl.im.sac.Model.Entidad
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2308)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1760)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.util.J2DoPrivHelper$7.run(J2DoPrivHelper.java:295)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.util.J2DoPrivHelper$7.run(J2DoPrivHelper.java:293)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceMetaDataDefaults.determineImplicitAccessType(PersistenceMetaDataDefaults.java:364)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceMetaDataDefaults.determineAccessType(PersistenceMetaDataDefaults.java:332)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceMetaDataDefaults.populate(PersistenceMetaDataDefaults.java:274)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.addMetaData(MetaDataRepository.java:914)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.addMetaData(MetaDataRepository.java:899)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.AnnotationPersistenceMetaDataParser.getMetaData(AnnotationPersistenceMetaDataParser.java:752)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.AnnotationPersistenceMetaDataParser.parseClassAnnotations(AnnotationPersistenceMetaDataParser.java:545)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.AnnotationPersistenceMetaDataParser.parse(AnnotationPersistenceMetaDataParser.java:415)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceMetaDataFactory.load(PersistenceMetaDataFactory.java:260)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaDataInternal(MetaDataRepository.java:580)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaDataInternal(MetaDataRepository.java:400)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaData(MetaDataRepository.java:384)
    at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancer.<init>(PCEnhancer.java:286)
    at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCEnhancer.<init>(PCEnhancer.java:257)
    at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCClassFileTransformer.transform0(PCClassFileTransformer.java:146)
    at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCClassFileTransformer.transform(PCClassFileTransformer.java:126)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.classForName(MetaDataRepository.java:1552)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.loadPersistentTypesInternal(MetaDataRepository.java:1528)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.loadPersistentTypes(MetaDataRepository.java:1506)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.loadPersistentTypes(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:282)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.initializeBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:238)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:212)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:227)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:154)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:60)
    at cl.im.sac.Dao.Persistencia.<clinit>(Persistencia.java:16)
    at cl.im.sac.Dao.ClienteDao.<clinit>(ClienteDao.java:17)
    at cl.im.sac.UI.Interfaz$1.actionPerformed(Interfaz.java:76)
```

This is the interface class.

```
public class Interfaz  extends JFrame{

    private JButton btnConsulta;
    ...

    public Interfaz(){
        super("Sistema de Atención Al Cliente");
        setContentPane(rootPanel);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(900,600);
        setVisible(true);


        /*** LISTENERS ***/
        btnConsulta.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String rn= run.getText();
                if (ValidateRUT.validate(rn)) {
                    Cliente cliente = ClienteDao.findByRUN(rn);
                    if (cliente != null) {
                        productos.setModel(new ProductoTableModel(cliente));
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El cliente no ha sido encontrado en el sistema");
                        }
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "RUN Inválido", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

the "Entidad" class is an abstract class that inherits the toString method.

```
public abstract class Entidad {

    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        try {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error al mapear la entidad";
        }
    }

}
```

and the "Cliente" class is part of the model database and extends "Entidad" class.

```
@Table(name = "cliente", catalog = "sac")
@Entity
public class Cliente extends Entidad implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;
    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Producto> productos;

    /** METHODS **/ 
}
```

Comment: I suppose an exception is thrown in `Entidad` in statement `private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();`. Wrap this in a static constructor, try/catch and output the exception. BTW, do you really have to use OpenJPA? I was very happy when I switched to EclipseLink and Hibernate is as well a very good choice.

Comment: works when I put run in intellij, but when creating the jar file, i open the application but does nothing. I think I'll have to try to change EclipseLink. thanks.